# run .apk file from emulator in Android

Tags: android, emulation, apk

I want to run .apk file from emulator but in the command line I am getting message **"error: device not found"** .How can I overcome this . PLease HELP. Thanks

Comment: look your DDMS . is it showing the emulator in device tab ??? If not than you should restart your emulator again.

Comment: close Eclipse and repeat or may be you have a problem with the emulator create new one. You can test if you have an emulator present by writtin "adb devices" in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same situation. You can do the following to detect the device again:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps ..

1: open the Eclipse i assume that u have install the android SDK in in eclipse

2: Start AVD Manager in your Eclipse by tracing the path "Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager"

3: Create your new AVD using the folowing link 
 "http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html"

4: Then start the AVD Using above link

5: open command promt in (for windows os ) , trace your android sdk pathe 
  LIKE -- "E:\abdroid-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb install F:\yourApplication.apk"

in this example the 'yourApplication.apk' is my apk which is in the F: drive

you may refer the following link for this insatllation

"http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator"